# How to find overlapping community structures using R?

Tags: r, networkx, igraph

I have two questions:

1- I was wondering if it is possible to uncover overlapping community structures in R using igraph ?

2- I found that LinkComm package can do something similar (find onverlapping community structures) but it cannot accept igraph networks, is it possible to apply LinkComm functions to an igraph graph ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by but it cannot accept igraph networks? Do you have an igraph and you want to apply LinkComm functions on it? It is not clear from your question what you have as inputs ? what do you try to get? what you have tried?

Comment: yest Agstudy, that's right. it cannot accept igraph graphs.

Comment: right? on what? I ask you some questions to clarify your first question... Obviously you don't get my point. The question as it is need some clarification, that 's why you don't have an answer after 4 hours.

Comment: Buddy, you are right on what you said "I have an igraph and I want to apply LinkComm Function on it".

Comment: I havent' donwvote! even your question is unclear at least for me. Try to produce what do you have as code and which function of LinkComm you want to apply. I really want to help you "Buddy". That's said I think you can save you igraph edges as a data.frame, create the lincomm object using this data.frame...But whithout code all this is juste a guess..

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarification, so here is the detail :
There is a graph, read from edgelist > 
g<-graph("graph.txt")
as.undirected(g)->g
getAllNestedComm(g)
The g in the last command has to be an object class of "linkComm"
But, the problem is there is no such function to convert the igraph object (graph) to linkcomm object (graph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a (rather dirty) trick to use the `linkcomm` package with `igraph` objects. The difficulty is that `linkcomm` uses the `igraph0` package and it uses the `igraph` objects' fields directly, and this *not* suggested. Their approach works with the `igraph0` package, but it does not with `igraph` package because `igraph` defines the `[[` indexing operator for igraph graphs.

Anyway, the following just overwrites a function from the `linkcomm` package. It works with package version 1.0-6 (2011-05-27), and it will almost surely not work with any other version. The proper fix would be updating the `linkcomm` package, by its author.

```
library(linkcomm)

# This will result a long warning about masked objects, because igraph 
# defines almost all names igraph0 defines, and linkcomm loads igraph0.
# But we are fine if we load igraph after linkcomm, because by default
# the igraph functions will be used
library(igraph)

# Modify the function from the linkcomm package, we create a new 
# function called 'lc'
lc <- as.list(getLinkCommunities)
lc[[11]][[10]][[3]] <- call("get.edgelist", quote(x), names=FALSE)
lc <- as.function(lc)

# Get some test data
karate <- nexus.get("karate")

# Use the newly defined 'lc' function on the test data
karcomm <- lc(get.data.frame(karate), check.duplicates=FALSE)
```

[image: result plot]

Comment: Thanks Gabor, please include this overlapping communities in your igraph package :), BTW a couple of new fast K-Clique algorithms are now emerged, it is worth to include them in your awesome igraph package.

Comment: You can make a feature request here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph

Comment: Can you please explain what does `community membership` plot mean when running the `linkcomm` demo?

Comment: @GaborCsardi When running your code I receive this error `> lc[[11]][[10]][[3]] <- call("get.edgelist", quote(x), names=FALSE)
Error in `*tmp*`[[10]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @MonaJalal: I don't know what it means, did I mention it anywhere?

Comment: @MonaJalal: `linkcomm` was updated, so you don't need this workaround any more. Just call `getLinkCommunities` on the graph.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I have a weighted graph stored in igraph. Would oc <- getLinkCommunities(get.data.frame(g)) fetch the weight on edges as well?